# Find the 2^k largest elements in O(n)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o

> Given an array A, the task is to find the largest, 2nd largest, 4th
> largest, 8th largest, 16th largest, ... and so on up to `2^logn`
> largest element. Give an `O(n)` algorithm to do this.

I do understand that elements need not to be sorted between the selected largest elements (for example between 4th and 8th largest). I also thought about using the `kth largest` elements algorithm but that would only save me sorting a small (largest) fraction of the array that is between `2^logn` and `max(n)` and it's not even `O(n)`.

I also thought about bucket sorting by splinting exponentially (instead of evenly) but this would still not provide me with the complexity guarantees that are required.

Comment: What is the range of values in the array?  Can they be any integer or is the range constrained?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah It's not constrained.

Answer (score 3):

If we assume quickselect (or some variant thereof) is O(n), then if we start at the `2^logn`th element, then extract all values that are less than it, then run the next query on those, etc., we would be halving `n` for our purpose each time. This would result in O(n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8...) = O(n).